# Login with google using passport js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, google-signin, google-developers-console, passport-google-oauth2

[https://github.com/harshitKyal/loginWithGoogle](https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2/tree/master/example)

this is my github repo link. I am using passport js to login with google . I created client key and secret key at google developer console. On running the code it is redirecting me to success page but req.user object is coming undefined. Please guide me through this. I took the code from https://github.com/mstade/passport-google-oauth2/tree/master/example

```
app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
        passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
            successRedirect: '/',
            failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
```

This code redirecting me to index page . But In index page I have written

```
<% if (!user) { %>
    <h2>Welcome! Please log in.</h2>
<% } else { %>
    <h2>Hello, <%= user.displayName %>.</h2>
<% } %>
```

It should display 
Hello and name of the user.

But instead of that , it is displaying Welcome!Please log in.

Comment: which solutions you have tried?

Comment: @harish I created client key and secret key and put it into the code. After login it redirects me to success page but with null req.user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codebase looks good. Noticed that you're using connection to redis server for storing session info:

```
store:  new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379
}),
```

did you start it? To check if your redis server is running and your application can connect to it, you can have a look to [debug output](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug):

```
export DEBUG=*
//and then run your app
node example/app.js
```

If you'll see a lot of errors, like:

```
    connect:redis Redis returned err { Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
```

Then, your redis connection is missing.

To fix this you can either:

a) install and run [redis](https://redis.io/download) locally

b) Use a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/). This requires [docker](https://www.docker.com/) to be installed. I did try it on MAC OS Sierra, it works well with command:

```
docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
```

Looks like this is the thing you've missed - start redis server. If you set it up - everything should work well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're excepting anything different than a User ID in `req.user`, you're returning bad info in your deseralize function.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});
```

You need to update it to actually get data from the Redis server.

From `serializeUser`, you get a user object that you need to turn into a user ID. If your ID is stored under `user.id`, then your function would look like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

From `deserializeUser`, you get a user ID that you need to turn into a user object. If you store your users in MongoDB (and you use mongoose), and the user ID is under `user.id`, your function would look like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne({ id: id }, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: user object is only coming null.